# Ice melting in a gravity-free room?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, surface-tension, fluid-statics

Consider an ice cube of side length $1 cm$ kept in a gravity free room i.e. room has zero gravity. Find the surface area of water after all the ice has melted. The densities of water and ice are to be considered equal.

---

My thought process behind this is as follows: 
Water tries to acquire minimum surface area, so it should form a spherical shape. Please correct me if I am wrong at this. If not, then how do I calculate the surface area of the sphere from the given data

Comment: Yes, that seems a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: @JohnRennie Alrighty. Thanks for confirming my doubt. I think I can manage the rest of the question. Thanks again 

Comment: Unless it is adsorbed on the wall, absorbed by the wallpaper :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add some experimental information that confirms your thought process from NASA SkyLab's [Classroom in Space](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-401/p134.htm), where a similar quantity of ice was melted on SkyLab compared to Ground Control - as per the diagrams below:

[image]

with the explanation:

> As water formed, it collected on the ice cylinder to give the ice/water combination a more spherical shape. On Earth, gravity would drain the liquid away from the ice. The time required for the ice to melt is increased in zero gravity because the layer of liquid insulates the ice from the surrounding warm air. It took approximately 190 minutes for the ice to melt in Skylab and only 130 minutes for it to melt in a duplicate experiment on Earth. The melting of ice simulated some of the fluid aspects of processing metals in zero gravity.

A full report of the experiment is in "[Observations of the liquid/solid interface in low-gravity melting](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19750027974)", stating a particular observation, that matches your thoughts (and the diagram above):

> At any time, the principle of minimum surface area governs the overall appearance of the water-ice globule which changed from a cylindrical to a spherical shape.